# Открытие аккордена при ховере (что бы не закрывался когда мышку убрали)

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

никогда не сталкивался с таким, подскажите как реализовать:
Ховер как на сайте < https://goclove.com/ >
Суть реализаци:
⦁   Ховер на название - открывается описание.
⦁   Ховер на другое название - открытое описание закрывается и открывается новое в соответствии с ховером.
⦁   Курсор уходит в сторону - описание остается открытым.
⦁   То есть описание реагирует на курсор.
⦁   Одно описание открыто всегда.
⦁   Размер фона подстраивается под количество текста, то есть расстояние от текста до края фона фиксированное.

Никогда с таким не сталкивался так как новичок в разработке, буду рад любой помощи)

Comment: и в чем сложность то? прикрутили событие mouseenter к заголовку да и все?, навели на заголовок, ранее открытое скрыли, новое открыли.

Comment: @teran
Спасибо, так и сделал:)